# Pytest mock fastapi.Depends upon direct function call

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, fastapi

How can we mock the `fastapi.Depends` function in a pytest?  It works if we access the function via `starlette.testclient.TestClient` (see 1st example below). It fails if we call the method directly (see 2nd example).

We know that we can override the Depends with `app.dependency_overrides[get_user] = ...` but same here, works when accessed via fastapi, fails when method is accessed directly.

We also tried mocking `Depends` but had no luck.

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()


def get_user(request: Request):
    # in real live we extract the user id from the header
    # request.headers.get(...)
    return "me"


@app.get("/one")
async def endpoint_one(user_id=Depends(get_user)):
    return {"user_id": user_id}

@app.get("/two")
async def endpoint_two(user_id=Depends(get_user)):
    result = await endpoint_one()  # <= the problem is here, since we do not pass the user_id
    return result

# works
def test_one():
    client = TestClient(app)
    result = client.get("/one")
    assert result.json()["user_id"] == "me"

# fails: as result is {'dependency': {}, 'use_cache': True}
def test_two():
    client = TestClient(app)
    result = client.get("/two")
    assert result.json()["user_id"] == "me"
```

Please note that this is a very simplified example.  In the real code the method that fails is far deeper in the hierarchy.  So we cannot change the `get_user` method or the corresponding call easily.

**Edit:** The key problem seems that we call the FastAPI endpoint directly deeper in the code.  Seems like this is not the recommended way (see https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/874).  Since this only "hurts" us in the tests we were looking for a solution like mocking to avoid a major code re-design.

Comment: Testing the route handler function directly seems weird to me. What's wrong with using the `TestClient`? You say that you cannot change the `get_user` easily, perhaps this is the issue that is worth solving.

Comment: For complex dependency management, consider using [dependency injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/). It plays really nicely with FastAPI and overriding any particular dependency is easy.

Comment: @PawełRubin the problem is that the call `user_list=await get_users(...)` is somewhere deep inside another FastAPI endpoint.  At those places we do not want to use requests/responses to get the user list but just call the method directly.
The dependency-injector could be a potential approach.  We will dig into that.  Thanks so far ;)

Comment: If the `get_users` call is a call to a 3rd party API, consider using the [pytest-httpx](https://github.com/Colin-b/pytest_httpx) (if you're using httpx for an HTTP client) or [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) (in case of requests) library to mock responses from 3rd party.

Comment: No `get_users` is our method.  Still we would like to avoid the http overhead when we need to access it internally so we invoke it directly.  Which works fine, except for the tests.

Comment: FastAPI has a [system for overriding dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/), which is really well suited for testing

Comment: @M.O. thanks, yes we know those, as mentioned in the question, but same here only works when called via TestClient and not directly.

Comment: Why do you want to call it directly?

Comment: See my previous comments.  Some of the API endpoints use each other under the hood and we do want to avoid the overhead of requests and response stuff.  As mentioned works 100% fine in the programm, the only issue is the tests above.

Comment: Why not just call `demo(get_user())`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct approach to handle this, but I had a similar issue when trying to test a deeply nested function that was using `Depends` and thus was not willing to use the override approach.

My "mock" was pretty simple, instead of trying to mock `fastapi.Depends` I just passed in my desired return value to replace the default parameter value.

So in your case something like:

```py
def test_method_call():
    result = demo(user_id="me")
    assert result["user_id"] == "me"
```

**Edit:**
Example for super simplistic "service" layer:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from myservice import one, two

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/one")
async def endpoint_one():
    return one()

@app.get("/two")
async def endpoint_two():
    return two()
```

```py
def get_user():
    # get user from somewhere
    return user

def one(user=Depends(get_user)):
    return user.id

def two():
    return one()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, as mentioned the method is nested deeper.  I will adjust my code example for better understandin.

Comment: Thanks :) I see, will check once you have updated it.
Anyways, I think the approach I showed can still help you, as it restricts the tested code to only the `demo` method and the `Depends` call can be replaced by your desired return value.

Comment: I checked your updated code example and I am not sure I understand the need for that approach.

For `endpoint_one` I see your comment that testing it works.

For `endpoint_two` I would suggest in general to not call your own API endpoints but rather a service layer that can be reused between different endpoints of your own application. In that case you could also easily mock the call to the "endpoint_one" service.

Comment: Do you have an example for that kind of service layer.  Inside the application we wanted to avoid the overhead: response = requests.get(...), result=response.json("result") or alike...

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in your example, but a very simple approach would be something like the example I added in my answer.

If you are using this as some sort of authentication (as suggested by extracting the user from the request (headers?), I would take a look at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/ as a very straightforward example of how to approach that.